# How to check if "Allow Multiple Apps" is disabled on iPad?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, multitasking, multi-window

My iOS application supports multiple window and when user disables the "Allow Multiple Apps" in settings, application couldn't open the new window.

Is there any way to identify what user has configured for "Allow Multiple Apps" So, that I can perform the task in the same window instead of going with new window.

I have tried checking with `UIDevice.current.isMultitaskingSupported`, It always returns true irrespective of the settings.